# Comprehension list on nested list (list of lists)

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension, nested-lists

It is allowed the use of a comprehension list on a "list of lists"?
I would like to extract a list from a nested list.
I did try this:

```
def main():
    a = ['1','2','3']
    b = ['4','5','6']
    c = ['7','8','9']
    board = [a,b,c]
    y = [x for x in board[1][i] if i in range(0,3)]
    print y
```

but I get "NameError: name 'i' is not defined".
I'm using the wrong syntax or nested list cannot be used like this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you expect the *output* to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesting loops in list comprehensions work the same way as nesting regular for loops, one inside the other:

```
y = [x for i in range(3) for x in board[1][i]]
```

but in this case, just selecting `board[1][:]` would be easier and give you the same result; a copy of the middle row.

If you need to apply an expression to each column in that row, then just loop over `board[1]` directly:

```
y = [foobar(c) for c in board[1]]
```

Comment: The comprehension list allows me to select a column too, not only a row. There is a faster way to return a column like you did with "board[1][:]" for the row?
Thanks!